# How can I refer a 3D pose (position + orientation) to a different coordinate system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems, rotations

I'm working on a robotics project where all poses and marker positions/orientations are stored as a matrix:
$$
        \mathbf{P} =\begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{R} & \mathbf{t}\\
        \mathbf{0} & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

With $\mathbf{R}$ being a rotation matrix and $\mathbf{t}$ being a translation vector.

Now if I have two poses like that: $\mathbf{P_1}$ and $\mathbf{P_2}$ with their rotation and translation expressed with respect to some absolute coordinate system, how can I express $\mathbf{P_2}$ with respect to $\mathbf{P_1}$?

I understand how that would happen if $\mathbf{P_1}$ had the same orientation as the original absolute coordinate system but I can't quite get my head around it when rotations come into play...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $P_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{R}_1 & \mathbf{t}_1\\
        \mathbf{0} & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$, $P_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{R}_2 & \mathbf{t}_2\\
        \mathbf{0} & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$:
\begin{align}
P_2 = P_2 P^{-1}_1 P_1 = P_2 \begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{R}^{\mathrm{T}}_1 & -\mathbf{R}^{\mathrm{T}}_1\mathbf{t}_1\\
        \mathbf{0} & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}P_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbf{R}_2\mathbf{R}^{\mathrm{T}}_1 & -\mathbf{R}_2\mathbf{R}^{\mathrm{T}}_1\mathbf{t}_1+t_2\\
        \mathbf{0} & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}P_1.
\end{align}
Notice that since $R_i$ are rotation matrices, $R^\mathrm{T}_iR_i = I$

Comment: So then (P_1)^(-1) * P_2 will give me the pose of P_2 in the P_1 coord system?

Comment: I think, now I understand your question a bit better. You want to express $P_2$ in terms of the coordinate system of $P_1$ which has the axis vectors $r_{11}+t_1,r_{12}+t_1,r_{13}+t_1$ right? ($r_{1i}$ are the columns of $R_1$), right?

Comment: I think so (I'm not sure what lowercase p's are in your notation). Imagine the original coordinate system at [0,0,0] gets transformed by applying $P_1$ to it. What is the pose $P_2$ in this new coordinate system - that's the question.

Comment: So if you want to transform a vector from the $P_2$ coordinate system into the $P_1$ coordinate system, then $P^{-1}_1P_2$, is the correct transformation.

If you want to express the rotation and translation of $P_2$ in terms of the $P_1$ coordinate system, then this should be $P^{-1}_1P_2P_1$:

$P1$ transforms a vector from your $P_1$ coordinates to your absolute coordinate system, then $P_2$ performs the rotation and translation of $P_2$ and $P^{−1}_1$ translates the resulting vector in absolute coordinates back into the $P_1$ transformed coordinates.